# Maintaining the Image thumbnail quality

Tags: html, image, image-processing, thumbnails

I have site where in I do client side image thumbnail preview with HTML 5 file reader interface.Everything works perfectly.However I see when I upload large size images lets say 600 by 600 , Image quality gets bad.I can understand that I shrink the size of the image and then display it.My image thumbnail placeholder is 300 by 300 and users can upload any size of the images.I need to maintain the quality of the images as given by the users.Is their anything I can do to maintain this on the client side ?Please read all dimension on pixels.
When I compare work with say facebook thumbnails, facebook thumbnails looks good even if they are shrunk in size.Appreciate if someone can point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques to reduce image dimensions that differ in the way the image is re-sampled. See if you can control the re-sampling method to change it to "Bilinear". "Nearest Neighbor" re-sampling tends to give out ragged looking images when reducing.

Comment: Can you elaborate more Oday, can you give me some links which I can explore.This is web application which I am working on.I am using HTML5 File reader interface to preview the images on the client.All preview work happens on the client and its non flash based solution which I have implemented.

Comment: This might be a good read: `https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering`. You're basically looking for `image-rendering: optimizeQuality;`. Skim through the webpage and look at the live examples halfway down, they should highlight the difference between resampling modes.